# using rc.local to start a jar file at startup is not working

Tags: java, linux, startup

I have a `.jar` file I want to run whenever the system reboots/starts, so I put the line

`nohup java -jar /mnt/fioa/fusion/nfs/labStats/LabInfoAutoLog.jar > /dev/null &`

in my `/etc/rc.local` file. The program is validated as working, and if I run the above command at the command line the program works as expected.

Other versions I have tried without success:

```
nohup /usr/bin/java -jar /mnt/fioa/fusion/nfs/labStats/LabInfoAutoLog.jar > /dev/null &
```

and:

```
nohup java -jar /mnt/fioa/fusion/nfs/labStats/LabInfoAutoLog.jar 2> /dev/null \ .. &
```

I am running centos 6.4.

Comment: Don't redirect the `stdout` & `stderr` to `/dev/null` but, at least for debugging, to some real log file (e.g. `>> /var/log/fioa-fusion.log`) then look inside. Perhaps `/mnt/fioa/` dont exist yet. Try to put your `LafInfoAutoLog.jar` e.g. under `/usr/local/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that your jar file is accesible roots, NFS mounted volumes may impose special restrictions for root.

Instead of discarding your error messages, you might want to route them to syslog, something like `2> /sbin/logger -t FOO 1> /sbin/logger -t BAR`

Comment: @cHam what settings did you set?

Comment: It was a long time ago, but if I recall I just used 'chmod 755 filename' where filename was whatever I was having trouble with at the time.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the path isn't set yet at startup time and you need the full path to the `java` executable or, possibly, `nohup`.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "the full path to the java executable" the full path to the jar file is listed, as is the path to java (in one example). As far as the path to nohup, how would I list that? I have never used rc.local or nohup in the past aside from this and It was working once before on the same machine. Not sure what would have changed to prevent it from working now.

Comment: When you install java on a linux computer, it puts a file named "java" somewhere and marks it executable. All the java standard library jars are installed somewhere nearby. You can type "path" and see where the shell looks for files to execute. The folder holding java will be in the path.